# Kentico multi language with multi domains

Tags: kentico

My build is English and French. I have a domain key for each in the system. I have my two cultures set as well, and I can not get this work correctly. my language toggle is based on the Kentico V8 Toggle, which currently gives the domain I Expect.

I'm making my changes in Chrome, and checking in IE, so I can see it not logged in.

Here's my setup:

- My domain alias is set to the French URL and the french culture. Default path and Redirect URL are blank.
- In Settings -> Content: Default culture is English. Combine check boxes are blank.
- In Settings -> URLS - SEO - Cultures, all check boxes are empty

I've also noticed the culture class on the BODY tag doesn't change to FRCA.

I'm hoping this is something simple, but from the documentation, i can't see what I've missed. Also, is the license key different for a alias domain?

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems with language switching in the past too. If your language switcher is custom code, try adding a `lang` querystring with value set to the target culture code (e.g. `domain.fr/?lang=fr-FR`). This has worked for me before.

Comment: For this build the requirement is a URL for domain. My other build here had the language query string but this is requirement is different.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working. Not sure if there was a iis cache issue. I'm going to reboot my local dev, and try across multiple browsers.